# Impossibility of probability measure on $2^{[0,1]}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega = [0, 1]$ and define a set function on the subsets $(a, b] \subset \Omega$ as $P( (a, b] ) = b-a$

Prove that no extension of $P$ from the subsets where it is defined to the power set of $\Omega$, $2^\Omega$ makes $P$ a probability measure on $\Omega$

$\text{i.e}$

Show that no extension of $P$ satisfy

1. $P(\Omega) = 1$
2. $P(\bigcup_{i = 0}^{\infty} A_i) = \sum_{i = 0} ^{\infty} P(A_i)$, where $A_i \cap A_j = \phi$ when $i\neq j$

Comment: I'm using the notation $2^\Omega$ to denote the power set of $\Omega$

Comment: if $P((a-b])=b-a$ then $P$ is the Lebesgue measure, and its very well known that the Lebesgue measure cannot be expanded to the power set. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set)

Comment: Actually, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945199/proving-vitali-set-is-non-measurable-set) might be a better duplicate. The answer is much clearer, imo.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Yes. I recall watching [How the Axiom of Choice Gives Sizeless Sets](https://youtu.be/hcRZadc5KpI) back in time. Realising just now that's exactly what plays here.